# Laravel Form Request validation not working with getValidatorInstance()

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've a simple array of rules in rules function:

```
return [
    'anumber'  => 'required|numeric'
];
```

And I fill this in getValidatorInstance method this way:

```
request()->merge(['anumber' => IdsCompany::getNumDBempty()]);
```

`getNumDBempty()` is working as expected, and returns an `int` or `false`, I want the validator to only accept the request if the function returns a number.

Controller method:

```
public function store(StoreIdsCompanyRequest $request, IdsCompany $ids_company_reg)
{

    //$ids_company_reg =  new IdsCompany;       

    $data   = request()->all();

    $user = User::find(auth()->id());

    $numEmpresasAsesor = DB::table('accesses')
        ->where('userId', '=', auth()->id())
        ->distinct('companyId')->count();

    if ($numEmpresasAsesor < ($user->consultant->asesorLimiteEmpresas))
    {
        if($ids_company_reg->createCompany_ForConsultant($data,$user->id))
        {           
            return redirect()->route('consultants.companies.index')->with('success',trans('textos.SACC_registro_guardado'));
        }
        else
        {                   
            return redirect()->route('consultants.companies.create')->withInput()->withErrors($ids_company_reg->errors);
        }

    }
    else
    {   
        $ids_company_reg->errors = new IlluminateMessageBag;
        $ids_company_reg->errors->add('error', trans('textos.CCF_numero_empresas')); 
        return redirect()->route('consultants.companies.create')->withInput()->withErrors($ids_company_reg->errors);
    }
}
```

The thing is that `anumber` is merged with the request but it keeps telling me that `anumber` is compulsory.

I've been fighting and searching for a couple of days, and I didn't find any clue of why the validator won't work on variables merged in `getValidatorInstance()`. (I've tried to validate this in others `FormRequest` and the result is the same, they ignore it like the variable was never there, but the request has it inside.)

Working in Laravel 5.5 atm, and planning to upgrade 5.6 when my form request are done and working.

Comment: Share your controller method and validator codes.

Comment: It shouldnt execute the controller method if the validation fails but here it comes:

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured it out:

It seems that the correct way to add new variables is this:

```
$data['anumber'] = IdsCompany::getNumDBempty();
```

And this to add it to the request:
    request()->merge(['anumber' => IdsCompany::getNumDBempty()]);